# Find usage of method in java (IntelliJ plugin development)

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ plugin. Here I got all `PsiMethod`s from a `PsiClass`. Now I want to get usages of that `PsiMethod`s that exist all over the project into a list. I tried different methods and but couldn't find a working one. Is there a way to do it?

*I want to get the usages of `PsiMethod`s **as a list of** `PsiElements`s

Comment: well, maybe there isn't a usage in your project. richt-click on the method name, find usages.

Comment: Something like the below code might help you.


` UsageInfo usageInfo = ((UsageInfo2UsageAdapter) usage).getUsageInfo();
        PsiElement currentElement = usageInfo.getElement();

        while (currentElement != null && !currentElement.toString().contains("PsiMethod:")) {
            currentElement = currentElement.getContext();
        }

        PsiElement codeBlockElement = currentElement;`

Answer (score 0):

click on the method name
and then `ALT+F7` [ this is in windows ]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the method choose the Find usages option or Alt + F7 shortcast.

Comment: I want to get the usages of `PsiMethod`s into a list of `PsiElements`s

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below code might help you.

```
 UsageInfo usageInfo = ((UsageInfo2UsageAdapter) usage).getUsageInfo();
 PsiElement currentElement = usageInfo.getElement();
        while (currentElement != null && !currentElement.toString().contains("PsiMethod:")) {
            currentElement = currentElement.getContext();
        }
```